The technician installed a new AC split without a vacuum pump
The technician installed a new AC split without a vacuum pump. (Gree 24000 BTU Inverter)
Should we drain the refrigerant, do vacuum, and refill the refrigerant?
It is written in the AC manual that we should vacuum during installation.
I read that air and humidity are harmful for the system and the compressor.

Is this a minisplit or a standard US whole house split a/c?

Sone minisplit systems now ship prefilled and do not need to be evacuated and then filled. Read the installation manuals for your specific product.

@JimStewart minisplit. (Gree lomo 24000 btu inverter)

@keshlam Unfortunately, No. Gree does not offer pre-charged linesets.
It is written in the AC manual that we should vacuum the pump during installation.
Should we evacuate the refrigerant, do vacuum, and refill with new refrigerant?

I would say you should withhold payment until the technician installs to manufacturer's specifications, gets the manufacturer to approve whatever procedure they used, or convinces you that they did it right and you just didn't notice.
